# GetProcAddress on managed C# dll

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to load C# dll through LoadLibrary. I am able to load it successfully. Can you please tell me how to use GetProcAddress for this dll so that i can use metods and types defined in this dlls.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

1 - Best way for this issue is COM. you should set the `AssemblyInfo` to expose the assembly as COM (`ComVisible(true)`). See this Microsoft suggestion:

- [How to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736)
- [Unmanaged to Managed calls (C++ to C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12662/Unmanaged-to-Managed-calls-C-to-C-without-Regasm)

2 - If you have Windows Vista or higher which has bitlocker, `BitLocker` can be useful.

3 - But if you cannot using COM, check out this on code-project:

- [Calling Managed Code from Unmanaged Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9903/Calling-Managed-Code-from-Unmanaged-Code-and-vice)

Comment: Are you checked out my new answer?

Comment: Actually i want to know is there any way to use methods and type defined in dll after loading from LoadLibrary....

Answer (score 0):

According to this link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/vcmfcatl/thread/cadd6150-de10-47c5-bd5c-a356741c36b3

GetProcAddress will always return NULL for a managed DLL, since it has no exports.

That being said, there are better ways to access managed code from unmanaged code.  You should create a C++/CLI wrapper around the unmanaged assembly, and then you can export the managed calls from inside the unmanaged wrapper functions.

Suppose one of your managed functions in class `A` is

```
public static void Foo() {}
```

You might have C++ code:

```
DLLEXPORT void FooThunk() {
    A::Foo();
}
```

PS: If anybody out there is comfortable with C++/CLI, please edit my answer to include a better example of such a wrapper.